# How to select an element of a pop up prompt using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a code using Selenium and Chromedriver to remotely control my instagram.

I've managed to login to the platform however as soon as I do a pop up asking about activating notifications appears and my codeflow breaks because it can no longer click the elements of the instagram page.

this is the code I tried using (which works during login to click the "send" button

```
notifBtn= self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button')
notifBtn.click()
```

(since it's the first instance of button on the web code it should automatically select that one)

however this time the browser is stuck and doesn't do anything.

during the login I had a problem where it wouldn't click either and found that it was because there was a lag between the request to go to the instagram login page and loading the page so it could find the CSS elements. I fixed it by adding

```
time.sleep(2)
```

before inputting the data and it fixed. I thought something similar would work here as it doesn't load instantly but it made no difference.

Is this an issue with the selector, as in could I use xpath to get around it? anyways sorry if it's a bit vague and feel free to ask me about my code or whatever.

```
notifBtn= self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button')
notifBtn.click()
```

I expect Chromedriver to click don't activate in the pop up so the code can continue instead I get stuck on that screen

Comment: It's hard to know what's wrong here without any context for the page you are testing. If you could post some of HTML on the page, including the button you are trying to click, and screenshot of the page with the alert you are encountering, this will be a good place to start.

Comment: I usually disable notifications by using prefs... so something like this:   prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);                 
                 chromeoptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

Comment: the new  "setUnhandledPromptBehaviour" option may work too...:  options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(promptBehaviorConstant);  You can use these constants:  UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.DISMISS, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE .  (or options which throw exceptions....)  Also using a WebDriverWait will be better than using a sleep.

Comment: @Christine Thank you, here is the link to the HTML and the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/BODKiLq

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks! that's a great idea, I didn't think about avoiding notifications altogether. I'll have a go at it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `find_element_by_css_selector` call is probably locating multiple elements, and doesn't know which one to click. I would use an XPath here, to be more explicit about which button you are trying to click:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# Wait for button to exist
not_now_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Not Now']")))

# Click the button
not_now_button.click()
```